# How to show media controls(Play, Pause) for audio file in jwplayer?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I am trying to play the audio file on my website using jwplayer, but it is not showing play, pause, and stop button. Please see below image and code for more information.

[image]

```
audioPlayer = jwplayer("audioplayerdiv");
audioPlayer.setup({
    file: filepath,
    height: 40
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to this problem. Actually, the play and pause button was loading on the page but don't know it was loaded with inline CSS display none property. Check the below code.

```
<div class="jw-icon jw-icon-inline jw-button-color jw-reset jw-icon-playback" style="display:  none;">
</div>
```

So, I just placed simple JQuesry code like below.

```
$('.jw-icon-playback').removeAttr('Style');
```

I know it is not a proper solution but after many tries, I found a little hack that worked for me. See here is the output.

[image]